# How can i make text printed to a label bold, italics or underlined?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

```
Dim enteredtext AS STRING = mytextbox.text

mylabel.content = enteredtext
```

How can i make the entered text that a user enters in a textbox be printed to a label as either bold italic or underlined. These three options shall be enabled with a radio button.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the font style for them.
e.g.:

```
mylabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Will see how i will work through them. If i have a problem i will ask more from you.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the below code.

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdBold" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Content="Bold" GroupName="format"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdItalics" Checked="rdItalics_Checked" Content="Italics" GroupName="format"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdUnderline" Checked="rdUnderline_Checked" Content="Underline" GroupName="format"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBx" Width="200" Height="20"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlk" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBx,Path=Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub RadioButton_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtBlk.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
    txtBlk.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal
    txtBlk.TextDecorations = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub rdItalics_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtBlk.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal
    txtBlk.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic
    txtBlk.TextDecorations = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub rdUnderline_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtBlk.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal
    txtBlk.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal
    txtBlk.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

As above if you are only doing this sometimes and wish to do it in the code behind you can use `mylabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic` or if the label always needs to be bold you can look at Font section in the properties tab and choose colur, size, bold, italics, underline, strikeout etc from there.